# WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "image"

Tags: gstreamer, pipeline

I have started working on gstreamer. I had a warning in the terminal command below; can you help me figure it out?

P. S. I had installed gstreamer successfully.

```
oddspin@oddspinl1:~$ gst-launch filesrc location=foto.jpg ! jpegdec ! image freeze ! mfw_isink
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "image"
```

Comment: I have figured out the error. I should loose the space between image and freeze. Thank you kaman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loose the space between "image" and "freeze" and you should be good.